# Invalid window handle

Tags: c#, window

I am writing an aplication to change position of window on the screan in c# using setwindowpos but when i want to get main window handle from Process class using MainWindowHandle all time I get zero. What I do it wrong.

```
public void run()
{

    string patch = "1.pdf";
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    pi.UseShellExecute = true;
    pi.FileName = @patch;
    p.StartInfo = pi;
    p.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    p.Refresh();
    IntPtr id = p.MainWindowHandle;
    Console.Write(id);
    Load.SetWindowPos(id, (IntPtr)HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0040);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos) is a good example that will help you. Also remember that the hese windows are ordered according to their appearance on the screen. The topmost window receives the highest rank and is the first window in the Z order.